# Cant call saved ItemQuery using REST

Tags: itemservice

Using Sitecore 9.2 and SXA 1.9, Im trying to call a saved item query by using the guid of the query item in the url

> /sitecore/api/ssc/item/{guid_of_query)/query

This gives a 400 error. What's wrong with that?

From what I've ready here, this should be correct:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html
[image]

Comment: Does the `{guid_of_query}` item from the request inherit Query Definition template?

Answer (score 1):

400 Error code usually means "Bad Request" which means that something has been forgotten that is expected in URL or there is a typo somewhere.

Based on Documentation page you have linked it means:

> Bad Request. This indicates that the request is not accepted by the server, perhaps because a parameter is invalid. It also indicates that you should not repeat the request. You get this response when the query definition item does not exist.

This error may indicate that:

1. Stored query is not based on template `/System/Services/Item Service/Query/Query Definition`
2. You are missing parameters in your request `?pageSize&page&database&includeStandardTemplateFields&fields`